# is there a way to use a subnetwork before pipeline starts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm writing a Dataflow Pipeline. It deserializes a confluent Avro PubSub subscription, and writes it to Google Big Query. Confluent Avro has a schema registry that we connect to in order to get the schema definition. We use Private Service Connect to have an IP of the form 192.168.x.x to connect to it.

I have this code:

```
         | "Write records to BigQuery" >> beam.io.Write(
             beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                 table=output_table,
                 dataset=output_dataset,
                 project=output_project,
                 schema=out_schema
                 create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.
                 CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                 write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)))
```

out_schema should be fetched from the SchemaRegistry using a function `fetchSchema()`. I want to create the table with out_schema when the pipeline starts if the table does not exist. I need to be able to fetch the schema before the pipeline starts in order to do that.

I can connect to the Schema Registry inside the pipeline, but I can't connect to it outside of the pipeline's functions and ParDo classes. When I try, I get 'connection refused'. I believe this is because the subnetwork I'm using is specified in the pipeline options.

Is there a way to use the subnetwork outside of the pipeline so I can connect to the schema registry before starting the pipeline?

```
def helper(record):
   logging.getInfo(fetchSchema()) #Works
   return record

fetchSchema() # Does not work
with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as pipeline:
   (pipeline | ... | beam.Map(lambda r: helper(r)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think a good approach to handle this would be to use [Flex Templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates).

When you create a job from a Flex Template, a GCE VM is created to run your program that creates the actual pipeline (which has to be packaged as a Docker container).

That launcher VM will be inside your VPC/network and should be able to talk to the schema registry.